# Eclipse - use autocomplete for project

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete folder (https://github.com/Garethp/ScreepsAutocomplete) that I want a project in Eclipse to use. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try doing what the readme said?

Comment: README is for Webstorm, since I don't use Eclipse. I'll be trying to add instructions for Eclipse soon...